# How to wrap an indexed SymPy expression into vectorized numeric function?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a system of differential equations that looks something like (apologies for the latex!)...

```
\dot{M}(t) = \sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}U_{ijk}(t) - M(t)

\dot{U}_{ijk}(t) = M_{i}(t) - U_{ijk}(t)
```

where `M` is actually a vector of length 4 and each of the indices `i,j,k` range from 0 to 3. I want to represent the RHS of this system using SymPy (primarily so that I can compute the Jacobian matrix for the system); and then wrap it so that it can be evaluated numerically.

I have been trying to use the following structures to represent `M` and `U`

```
# males carrying a particular genotype
males = sym.DeferredVector('M')

# families configurations are represented by a symbolic tensor
U = sym.tensor.IndexedBase('U', shape=(4, 4, 4))
```

These structures have allowed me to represent the RHS in SymPy, but the following error is raised when I try to compute the Jacobian

```
ValueError: 
Can't calculate 1-th derivative wrt U[0, 0, 0].
```

Additionally, when I try to `lambdify` the expression I get an error

```
my_18 + _Dummy_20) + (-_Dummy_25 + 1)*(-_Dummy_27 + 1)*(_Dummy_17 + _Dummy_19))**2 - U[3, 3, 3]]]))
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From other SO questions I suspect that the problem is my use of `IndexedBase` in representing the RHS of my system.  Perhaps I should be using some other technology to wrap my symbolic expression into a vectorized numeric function? Perhaps `autowrap`?

Comment: The problem is that `IndexedBase` isn't handled very well in functions like `lambdify` and `jacobian`.